# I have a requirement for a client, where they want to collect response from the user who directly emails them on their sap domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, sender-authentication-package, reply-mail-management, sfmcadmin

I have a requirement for a client, where they want to collect response from the user who directly emails them on their sap domain.

When the client sends an email from their SAP domain lets say abc@xyz.com, when someone receives the email and instead of hitting reply, they copy the from email address(abc@xyz.com) and send a reply email back, then can we setup a mailbox to catch those replies somehow so they don't get lost?

Answer (score 0):

There won't necessarily be a physical mailbox attached to your SAP domain.

It would be better to attach a monitored inbox email address in Reply Mail Management for customers to reply to. It seems unlikely that a customer would copy and paste your SAP Domain Sender Email and not use the standard reply function.